# Why was implicit presence with commonly used defaults decided for Protobuf v3?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm new to Protobuf v3.

It seems per this [doc](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/docs/field_presence.md) that Protobuf v3 has implicit presence of fields. Thus, there is no way for a receiver of a Protobuf message to know whether

- the sender manually set the default value
- the sender didn't set a value (in which the default is used)

My question is - why was this decision made?

Let's say for example that I have a field in a Protobuf message called `num_children`, e.g.

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

message Family {
  uint32 num_children = 1;
}
```

As a receiver of `Family` messages if I see `num_children = 0` I have no way of knowing if the family actually has 0 children or if the sender forgot to specify the number of children.

At first glance, this appears to me to be a design flaw. What's the reasoning for this? And what're the best practices around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news. Presence detection is now back in proto3 and has been for a few months. Just add `optional` before the fields - they'll be optional either way (in proto3), but this keyword enables presence tracking. This solves the problem of implicit vs explicit default values. It is a bit confusing that `optional` now means something completely different here, but that's probably better than the problems associated with adding a new keyword/syntax!

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

message Family {
  optional uint32 num_children = 1;
}
```

The document you link to is out of date; this is no longer an experimental feature, and is enabled by default.